# не удается подключить библиотеку SVGPATHTOOLS

Tags: python, python-3.x, svg, pip

не удается подключить библиотеку SVGPATHTOOLS (pip3 install svgpathtools) через терминал на макбуке m1

код ошибки:

```
pip3 install svgpathtools
Requirement already satisfied: svgpathtools in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/svgpathtools-1.5.1-py3.10.egg (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from svgpathtools) (1.23.3)
Collecting svgwrite
  Using cached svgwrite-1.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-1.9.1.tar.gz (42.0 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [61 lines of output]
      The Meson build system
      Version: 0.62.2
      Source dir: /private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-install-gbggfcoe/scipy_b6d65ad1531f42739d7893bc7689fd11
      Build dir: /private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-install-gbggfcoe/scipy_b6d65ad1531f42739d7893bc7689fd11/.mesonpy-vcrggrnu/build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: SciPy
      Project version: 1.9.1
      C compiler for the host machine: cc (clang 13.0.0 "Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)")
      C linker for the host machine: cc ld64 711
      C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (clang 13.0.0 "Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)")
      C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld64 711
      Host machine cpu family: aarch64
      Host machine cpu: arm64
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: NO
      Library m found: YES
      
      ../../meson.build:41:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['gfortran'], ['flang'], ['nvfortran'], ['pgfortran'], ['ifort'], ['g95']]
      The following exception(s) were encountered:
      Running "gfortran --version" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gfortran'"
      Running "gfortran -V" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gfortran'"
      Running "flang --version" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flang'"
      Running "flang -V" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flang'"
      Running "nvfortran --version" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvfortran'"
      Running "nvfortran -V" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvfortran'"
      Running "pgfortran --version" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pgfortran'"
      Running "pgfortran -V" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pgfortran'"
      Running "ifort --version" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifort'"
      Running "ifort -V" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifort'"
      Running "g95 --version" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'g95'"
      Running "g95 -V" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'g95'"
      
      A full log can be found at /private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-install-gbggfcoe/scipy_b6d65ad1531f42739d7893bc7689fd11/.mesonpy-vcrggrnu/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
      + meson setup --native-file=/private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-install-gbggfcoe/scipy_b6d65ad1531f42739d7893bc7689fd11/.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2 --prefix=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10 /private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-install-gbggfcoe/scipy_b6d65ad1531f42739d7893bc7689fd11 /private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-install-gbggfcoe/scipy_b6d65ad1531f42739d7893bc7689fd11/.mesonpy-vcrggrnu/build
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-s_fgd37t/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 923, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          with _project(config_settings) as project:
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
          return next(self.gen)
        File "/private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-s_fgd37t/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 902, in _project
          with Project.with_temp_working_dir(
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
          return next(self.gen)
        File "/private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-s_fgd37t/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 547, in with_temp_working_dir
          yield cls(source_dir, tmpdir, build_dir)
        File "/private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-s_fgd37t/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 463, in __init__
          self._configure(reconfigure=bool(build_dir) and not native_file_mismatch)
        File "/private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-s_fgd37t/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 494, in _configure
          self._meson(
        File "/private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-s_fgd37t/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 477, in _meson
          return self._proc('meson', *args)
        File "/private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-s_fgd37t/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 472, in _proc
          subprocess.check_call(list(args))
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['meson', 'setup', '--native-file=/private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-install-gbggfcoe/scipy_b6d65ad1531f42739d7893bc7689fd11/.mesonpy-native-file.ini', '-Ddebug=false', '-Doptimization=2', '--prefix=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10', '/private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-install-gbggfcoe/scipy_b6d65ad1531f42739d7893bc7689fd11', '/private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-install-gbggfcoe/scipy_b6d65ad1531f42739d7893bc7689fd11/.mesonpy-vcrggrnu/build']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

> после установки фортрана

```
pip3 install svgpathtools
Requirement already satisfied: svgpathtools in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/svgpathtools-1.5.1-py3.10.egg (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from svgpathtools) (1.23.3)
Collecting svgwrite
  Using cached svgwrite-1.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-1.9.1.tar.gz (42.0 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [62 lines of output]
      The Meson build system
      Version: 0.62.2
      Source dir: /private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-install-_o8blutt/scipy_197e756f050646d785f6cfade6b960e9
      Build dir: /private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-install-_o8blutt/scipy_197e756f050646d785f6cfade6b960e9/.mesonpy-2cmadeio/build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: SciPy
      Project version: 1.9.1
      C compiler for the host machine: cc (clang 13.0.0 "Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)")
      C linker for the host machine: cc ld64 711
      C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (clang 13.0.0 "Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)")
      C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld64 711
      Host machine cpu family: aarch64
      Host machine cpu: arm64
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: NO
      Library m found: YES
      Fortran compiler for the host machine: gfortran (gcc 12.2.0 "GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 12.2.0) 12.2.0")
      Fortran linker for the host machine: gfortran ld64 711
      Program cython found: YES (/private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-569u2w64/overlay/bin/cython)
      Program pythran found: YES (/private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-569u2w64/overlay/bin/pythran)
      Program cp found: YES (/bin/cp)
      Program python3 found: YES (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10)
      Did not find pkg-config by name 'pkg-config'
      Found Pkg-config: NO
      Library npymath found: YES
      Library npyrandom found: YES
      Did not find CMake 'cmake'
      Found CMake: NO
      Run-time dependency openblas found: NO (tried pkgconfig, framework and cmake)
      Run-time dependency openblas found: NO (tried framework)
      
      ../../scipy/meson.build:130:0: ERROR: Pkg-config binary for machine 1 not found. Giving up.
      
      A full log can be found at /private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-install-_o8blutt/scipy_197e756f050646d785f6cfade6b960e9/.mesonpy-2cmadeio/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
      + meson setup --native-file=/private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-install-_o8blutt/scipy_197e756f050646d785f6cfade6b960e9/.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2 --prefix=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10 /private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-install-_o8blutt/scipy_197e756f050646d785f6cfade6b960e9 /private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-install-_o8blutt/scipy_197e756f050646d785f6cfade6b960e9/.mesonpy-2cmadeio/build
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-569u2w64/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 923, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          with _project(config_settings) as project:
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
          return next(self.gen)
        File "/private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-569u2w64/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 902, in _project
          with Project.with_temp_working_dir(
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
          return next(self.gen)
        File "/private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-569u2w64/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 547, in with_temp_working_dir
          yield cls(source_dir, tmpdir, build_dir)
        File "/private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-569u2w64/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 463, in __init__
          self._configure(reconfigure=bool(build_dir) and not native_file_mismatch)
        File "/private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-569u2w64/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 494, in _configure
          self._meson(
        File "/private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-569u2w64/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 477, in _meson
          return self._proc('meson', *args)
        File "/private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-569u2w64/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 472, in _proc
          subprocess.check_call(list(args))
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['meson', 'setup', '--native-file=/private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-install-_o8blutt/scipy_197e756f050646d785f6cfade6b960e9/.mesonpy-native-file.ini', '-Ddebug=false', '-Doptimization=2', '--prefix=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10', '/private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-install-_o8blutt/scipy_197e756f050646d785f6cfade6b960e9', '/private/var/folders/nk/wbll_cvx65q2vmcqj2zj9gjh0000gn/T/pip-install-_o8blutt/scipy_197e756f050646d785f6cfade6b960e9/.mesonpy-2cmadeio/build']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: Судя по ошибке, нужно компилятор фортрана установить.

Comment: я установил фортран. посмотри пожалуйста на правку

Comment: Теперь требует openblas: `Run-time dependency openblas found: NO (tried framework)`. Вообще не в курсе что это. Пробуйте гуглить устанавливать.